# Mongodb difference between condition with $and operator and without the operator

Tags: mongodb, filter, operators

Is there a difference between condition for Mongodb in form

```
{$and: [{a: 'aaa'}, {b: 'bbb'}]}
```

and the sam condition without $and operator

```
{a: 'aaa', b: 'bbb'}
```

Somebody told me the $and operator slows the query. Is it true? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no difference between those conditions. The best way to answer questions like this is to look at [`explain`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#cursor.explain) output to take a look at how Mongo actually handles a query like this.

If you take a look at the `winningPlan` in the query-plans below, you can see that they're exactly the same! Just because the `$and` isn't explicit in `{a: 'aaa', b: 'bbb'}` doesn't mean it's not there: it's just implicit.

`> db.my_test_coll.createIndex({a: 1, b: 1}); // adding an index`

**Without the `$and`:**

```
> db.my_test_coll.find({a: 'aaa', b: 'bbb'}).explain()
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.my_test_coll",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "a" : {
                        "$eq" : "aaa"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "b" : {
                        "$eq" : "bbb"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "a" : 1,
                    "b" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "a_1_b_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "a" : [ ],
                    "b" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "a" : [
                        "[\"aaa\", \"aaa\"]"
                    ],
                    "b" : [
                        "[\"bbb\", \"bbb\"]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**With the `$and`:**

```
> db.my_test_coll.find({$and: [{a: 'aaa'}, {b: 'bbb'}]}).explain()
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.my_test_coll",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "a" : {
                        "$eq" : "aaa"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "b" : {
                        "$eq" : "bbb"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "a" : 1,
                    "b" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "a_1_b_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "a" : [ ],
                    "b" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "a" : [
                        "[\"aaa\", \"aaa\"]"
                    ],
                    "b" : [
                        "[\"bbb\", \"bbb\"]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Ok but is it the same in all situations?

Comment: Speedwise, yes. Sometimes you need to explicitly use $and when you're referencing the same field, but it's rare. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/ for an example

Comment: Without the `$and` doesn't mean the `$and` isn't there -- it's just implicit!

Comment: The latest comment should be added how a special block/note in your answer