# MongoDB: Arrays size with $where - ReferenceError

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

For MongoDB *4.4.6*

For a collection with an array - If I use

```
db.fighters.find({"close_attacks": {$size: 3}},
                 {"_id": 0, "biography": 0})
           .pretty()
db.fighters.find({"close_attacks.2" : { $exists: true }},
                 {"_id": 0, "biography": 0})
           .pretty()
db.fighters.find({"close_attacks.3" : { $exists: true }},
                 {"_id": 0, "biography": 0})
           .pretty()
```

All work in peace

I want work with `>=#` (i.e *>=3*), I did do a research, and in many posts in SO appear two options, one already shown above: *working with the index of the array and #exists*, the other is working with `$where`

So in Compass through _*mongosh beta* I tried:

```
db.fighters.find({$where: "this.close_attacks.length >= 3"},
                 {"_id": 0, "biography": 0})
           .pretty()
```

and arises

```
MongoError: TypeError: this.close_attacks is undefined :
@:1:15
```

If I remove `this`

```
db.fighters.find({$where: "close_attacks.length >= 3"},
                 {"_id": 0, "biography": 0})
           .pretty()
```

it arises

```
MongoError: ReferenceError: close_attacks is not defined :
@:1:15
```

What is missing or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#mongodb-query-op.-expr) operator to use aggregation operator `$gte` and `$size`,

> **Aggregation Alternatives Preferred**
> Starting in MongoDB 3.6, the `$expr` operator allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language.

```
db.fighters.find({
  $expr: {
    $gte: [{ $size: "$close_attacks" }, 3]
  }
},
{"_id": 0, "biography": 0}).pretty()
```

> *MongoError: The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing*

You can avoid such error by checking its type using `$type`,

```
db.fighters.find({
  $and: [
    { close_attacks: { $type: "array" } },
    {
      $expr: {
        $gte: [{ $size: "$close_attacks" }, 3]
      }
    }
  ]
},
{"_id": 0, "biography": 0}).pretty()
```

> **NOTE:**
> Starting in MongoDB 4.4, `$where` no longer supports the deprecated BSON type JavaScript code with scope (BSON type 15). The `$where` operator only supports BSON type String (BSON type 2) or BSON type JavaScript (BSON type 13). The use of BSON type JavaScript with scope for `$where` has been deprecated since MongoDB 4.2.1.

The two blocks are available in [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)

Comment: My 2 `$where` expressions what BSON types are? They are failing due that, right? Seems the former is 15, but for the latter I'm not sure what type is

Comment: Something is wrong - it arises: `MongoError: The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing`

Comment: your first `$where` query with `this` is correct, but yah it is failing because of type 15. `The argument to $size must be an array` it is because there different type value in `close_attacks` field. so $size operator needs only array type input.

Comment: The `close_attacks` is an array based on String - how fix that error message?

Comment: see i have updated answer, check condition by field type should be an array.

Comment: Thank you, just being curious, the first approach when should work without any problem? I saw here the same approach - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48410837/3665178 - now what is mandatory the second approach?

Comment: what is first approach? are you talking about $where or $expr? or $expr with $type?

Comment: First approach without `$and: [...`, second approach with `$and: [` - of your two solutions

Comment: its just wrapper, just for a clear view and make sure that you are managing conditions properly, can use without it `{ close_attacks: { $type: "array" }, $expr: { $gte: [{ $size: "$close_attacks" }, 3] } }`, there are parcing issues in some language sdk so that is why I have wrapped it to `$and`.

Comment: for information: in background mongodb will wrap that conditions by `$and` operator you can see it using `explain()` function.

Comment: `"there are parcing issues in some language sdk so that is why I have wrapped it to $and"` Interesting, I am just using MongoDB Compass

Comment: *I am just using MongoDB Compass* sorry for that I missed that, I just used the standard approach.

Comment: Don't worry, but if I used Compass through two ways: "Documents -> Filters" and its own "mongosh beta" terminal - not sure what do you mean with _"standard approach"_

Comment: called mongodb implicit approach, implicitly it will wrap in `$and` to execute match in sequence. see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54750316/mongodb-difference-between-condition-with-and-operator-and-without-the-operator).