# Mongo: Array size between a range (inclusive and exclusive)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

For Mongo, for an array I am able to use in peace:

```
db.fighters.find({"close_attacks": {$size: 3}},
                 {"_id": 0, "biography": 0})
           .pretty()
```

and same for `>`, `≥`, `<` and `≤`, for example:

- *2>*
- *2≥*
- *<5*
- *≤5*

Therefore the query would be as template for example:

```
db.fighters.find({$and: [{"close_attacks": {$type: "array"}},
                         {$expr: {$X: [{$size: "$close_attacks"}, 3]}}]})
```

Where `$X` can be any of `$lt`, `$lte`, `$gt` and `$gte`

About the pattern shown above see:

- [MongoDB: Arrays size with $where - ReferenceError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67791958/mongodb-arrays-size-with-where-referenceerror)

I want to know if is possible and how declare **one** query but working with a range about the size, such as:

- *2> and <5* (exclusive)
- *2≥ and ≤5* (inclusive)

Comment: You can build the query filter based upon _some input_ - and use that filter with the query. For example, like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69367673/mongoose-find-function-is-there-a-value-for-in-which-would-be-true-no-matter-w/69370680#69370680 . So does your query take any inputs to determine the range, for example?

Comment: You can use another `$and` insided that expr to pass both conditions, exactly like you do it at the first level.

Comment: You have **one** query! What is your question?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I have currently one query without a range. The question is have one query with a range or between of dates.

Comment: @prasad_ I saw your link, the query requested should be easy/simple.

Comment: Try this with an `$and` operator: `$expr: { $and: [  { $gt: [ { $size: "$close_attacks" }, 2 ] }, { $lt: [ { $size: "$close_attacks" }, 5 ] } ] }`